# extracting dataframe out of json file with same key values

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

i have a json file(given below), i need to extract a **dataframe** with column names as value of **"jive_label"** inside **profile**[] and values as its values, expected output given below. also i have given the sample code where i try to print just one column, but that code clearly doesnt work.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import sys
import json


r=requests.get(url,data=payload,headers=headers,params=querystring,verify=False)
json_data=r.json()
df=pd.DataFrame([])
    for i in json_data.get('profile',[]):
        if i.get('jive_label')=='Title':

            dfDict={'Title': i.get('value')
                   }
         df=df.append(pd.DataFrame(dfDICT,index=[0]),ignore_index=True)
    print(df.head())*


  {
        "jive": {
                "enabled": true,
                "external": false,
                "federated": true,
                "lastProfileUpdate": "2017-08-14T17:07:35.491+0000",
                "level": {
                    "description": "Level 1",
                    "imageURI": "https:",
                    "name": "Newbie",
                    "points": 0
                },
                "locale": "en_US",
                "externalContributor": false,
                "profile": [
                    {
                        "jive_label": "Title",
                        "value": "Analyst",
                        "jive_displayOrder": 0,
                        "jive_showSummaryLabel": false
                    },
                    {
                        "jive_label": "COMPANY ID",
                        "value": "333333",
                        "jive_displayOrder": 5,
                        "jive_showSummaryLabel": false
                    },
                    {
                        "jive_label": "Department",
                        "value": "46152",
                        "jive_displayOrder": 6,
                        "jive_showSummaryLabel": false
                    },
                    {
                        "jive_label": "BUFUGU",
                        "value": "C06",
                        "jive_displayOrder": 9,
                        "jive_showSummaryLabel": false
                    },
                    {
                        "jive_label": "XYZ Company Code",
                        "value": "DA01",
                        "jive_displayOrder": 10,
                        "jive_showSummaryLabel": false
                    },
                    {
                        "jive_label": "Business Purpose",
                        "value": "C0820",
                        "jive_displayOrder": 11,
                        "jive_showSummaryLabel": false
                    },
                    {
                        "jive_label": "Company",
                        "value": "XYZ",
                        "jive_displayOrder": 19,
                        "jive_showSummaryLabel": false
                    },
                    {
                        "jive_label": "Street Address",
                        "value": "30 NY NY",
                        "jive_displayOrder": 20,
                        "jive_showSummaryLabel": false
                    },
                    {
                        "jive_label": "City",
                        "value": "NYC",
                        "jive_displayOrder": 21,
                        "jive_showSummaryLabel": false
                    },
                    {
                        "jive_label": "Province/State",
                        "value": "NY",
                        "jive_displayOrder": 22,
                        "jive_showSummaryLabel": false
                    },
                    {
                        "jive_label": "Postal/Zip Code",
                        "value": "00000",
                        "jive_displayOrder": 23,
                        "jive_showSummaryLabel": false
                    },
                    {
                        "jive_label": "Country",
                        "value": "United States",
                        "jive_displayOrder": 24,
                        "jive_showSummaryLabel": false
                    },
                    {
                        "jive_label": "Preferred Language",
                        "value": "E",
                        "jive_displayOrder": 30,
                        "jive_showSummaryLabel": false
                    },
                    {
                        "jive_label": "Display Name",
                        "value": "P, M",
                        "jive_displayOrder": 31,
                        "jive_showSummaryLabel": false
                    },
                    {
                        "jive_label": "ReportsTo",
                        "value": "529847279",
                        "jive_displayOrder": 37,
                        "jive_showSummaryLabel": false
                    },
                    {
                        "jive_label": "Transit Number",
                        "value": "46152",
                        "jive_displayOrder": 38,
                        "jive_showSummaryLabel": false
                    },
                    {
                        "jive_label": "Transit Description",
                        "value": "A B C D",
                        "jive_displayOrder": 39,
                        "jive_showSummaryLabel": false
                    }
                ],
        }
```

expected output:[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using pandas `from_dict` is one way to solve this:

```
# normalize your dict and drop unwanted fields
data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(myjson['jive']['profile']).drop(['jive_displayOrder','jive_showSummaryLabel'], axis=1)

# reshape the data
data = pd.pivot_table(data, index=None, columns='jive_label', values='value', aggfunc='max')

# remove unwanted names
data.columns.name = None
data.reset_index(drop=True)

print(data)

   BUFUGU  BusinessPurpose COMPANY ID   City    Company     Country     Department  Display Name    Postal/Zip Code Preferred Language  Province/State  ReportsTo Street Address Title Transit Description  Transit Number  XYZ Company Code
0   C06     C0820   333333  NYC     XYZ     United States   46152   P, M    00000   E   NY  529847279   30 NY NY    Analyst     A B C D     46152   DA01
```

Comment: actually the json ithat i have given is part of a big json response of an api call. so when i run your code it gives an error like  - KeyError: 'jive'      so it should be in a loop may be ? i am not sure

Comment: Isn't jive a key of the big json ?

Comment: hey do you mind helping me with his one https://stackoverflow.com/q/49515298/6067089 , i am so stuck !

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

with open('data.json') as fd:
    data = json.load(fd)

profile = data['jive']['profile']
headers = [e['jive_label'] for e in profile]
values  = [e['value']      for e in profile]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=headers, data=[values])
```

Comment: Glad it helped. Please close the question by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer that helped you the most. Thanks.