# merging dataframes from 2 different api get calls in python

Tags: python, json, rest, api, dataframe

i am a beginner in python, i have two codes that work perfect when run separately. but doesnt work when i put them in functions in one single program.

**1)** in one i get a json response  with details of 100 douments in a particular website

**2)** in the second code i get the details of the author of each of that document with authorID retrieved from first code .

So i have to retrieve authorID from the first code and pass it to the url endpoint of the api call in the second code. and then merge the 2 dataframes in the main function with common authorID.

url="https://api-jj.com/ugt0/xyz/v1/people/%authorID" this works when 
it is given like this url="https://api-jj.com/ugt0/xyz/v1/people/314684"

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import sys
import json
import csv

global headers
headers = {
    'ConnectAuthorization': "Basic z",
    'Authorization': "Bearer Q",
    'Cache-Control': "no-cache",
    'Postman-Token': "1"
    }
global payload
payload=''

r=requests.get(url,data=payload,headers=headers,verify=False)
json_data=r.json()


def get_contendetails():
    try:


        url="https://api/ugt0/xyz/v1/contents?count=100"
        r=requests.get(url,data=payload,headers=headers,verify=False)
        json_data=r.json()
        if json_data =='' or None :
            return [], 'Got empty response'
        else:
            for i in json_data.get('list',[]):
                dfDICT = {'Content_id':[i.get('contentID',None)],
                          'subject':[i.get('subject',None)],
                          'published':[i.get('published',None)],
                          'updated':[i.get('updated',None)],
                          'likeCount':i.get('likeCount',None),
                          'replyCount':i.get('replyCount',None),
                          'viewCount':i.get('viewCount',None)
                          }

                if i.get('author',None):  # Test if your key exists
                    dfDICT['Author'] = i.get('author').get('displayName',None)

                else:
                    dfDICT['Author'] = None
                if i.get('author',None):
                    dfDict['authorID']=i.get('author').get('id',None)
                else:
                    dfDICT['authorID']=None

            df1=df1.append(pd.DataFrame(dfDICT,index=[0]),ignore_index=True)
            return df1





def get_authordetails(authorID):
    try:
        url="https://api-jj.com/ugt0/xyz/v1/people/%authorID"
        r=requests.get(url,data=payload,headers=headers,verify=False)
        json_data=r.json()
        if json_data =='' or None :
            return [], 'Got empty response'
        else:
            for j in [json_data]:
                profile = j['jive']['profile']
                headers = [e['jive_label'] for e in profile]
                values  = [e['value'] for e in profile]

            df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=headers, data=[values]).drop('BUFUGU','Preferred Language'axis[0])

            return df2
def main():
   s=get_contendetails()
   v=get_contendetails(authorID)
   f=pd.merge(s,v)
```

dataframe of first part of code with content details :
[image]

dataframe of second part of code with detail of one author:

[image]

Comment: Is this question still open or solved?

Comment: its still open !